# .Net Windows Installer Custom Interface - Diff between Install and Administrative Install

Tags: windows-installer, installation, administrative

I am creating a .msi file using visual studio. I would like to know the difference between Install and Administrative install in the custom interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a normal install is what you usually think of, an admin install copies the source image of the application to a network share or other location so that you can install copies from that share.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48h5xkw(VS.71).aspx